# CMMotionActivity startDate is 1970 not 2016

Tags: ios, core-motion

My CMMotionActivity object has the property timestamp and startDate.

Printing both of these shows the value is from 1970, not 2016 as expected.

```
[self.motionActivityManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {
    NSLog(@"startDate = %@",activity.startDate);
    NSLog(@"timestamp = %f",activity.timestamp);
}];
```

> 2016-07-20 17:46:53.294 MyApp[292:30246] timestamp = 8648.852289
>
> 2016-07-20 17:46:54.229 MyApp[292:30246] startDate = 1970-01-01 02:24:09 +0000

My device's time and date is set correctly, though it has been turned off for weeks.

EDIT: Today I got this: No code changes.

> 2016-07-21 11:26:34.292 MyApp[229:7473] startDate = 2016-07-21 10:26:34 +0000
>
> 2016-07-21 11:26:34.293 MyApp[229:7473] timestamp = 662.524030

Eh... Close enough. "timestamp" (from NSLogItem) is a NSTimeInterval so a phone running time or something.

I guess 24hrs or a phone reboot fixes the issue.